# unable to train custom object detection in TF2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

i using tensorflow gpu to train custom object detection for single object. If i execute train command i am facing the below issue,

```
(tensor_gpu) C:\Users\admin\Downloads\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr 
--train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
2019-12-02 16:21:53.124045: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] 
Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 48, in
from tensorflow.contrib import framework as contrib_framework
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

kindly look on this issue and give some suggestions..

Comment: The object detection API does not yet support TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: ```tensorflow.contrib``` has been removed in TensorFlow 2.0, see here: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md

Comment: In TF2.0 any syntax replaced for tensorflow.contrib .

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Reason for this error is 'tensorflow.contrib' has been removed from the packages.

Since all the projects in `tf.contrib` were not officially supported by Tensorflow and it had designated owners for maintaining it.

From the Tensorflow 2.0 version all the contrib projects had one of three options for its future: `move to core`; `move to a separate repository`; or `delete`, most of which have been reviewed with the respective project owners.

This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) provides the details and status for all the projects under `tf.contrib`.

If the library you are using is moved to the core or separate repository, the TensorFlow's automatic code migration from 1.x to 2.x will not work for `tf.contrib` projects.  You need to change your code manually for these parts, which is suggested going forward.

I can see in the table that `tf.contrib.slim` is moved to `tensorflow/models` , you can follow this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) for the usage in detail.